# Application settings in visual studio 2008 express edition, winforms

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

In the application settings screen for the express edition, the Configuration combo box is disabled, so I can't change things like the assembly name and description depending on the configuration.

The first question is, is this box enabled in the full version?

Secondly, to get around this, I edited the AssemblyInfo file manually and used preprocessor directives to change the assembly description depending on the configuration.

This works, and each configuration compiles correctly. If I then right click each dll, I can see that the description is different for each one.

My question is, is it ok to do this or might I run into problems at some point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, this is OK. Even if you change these settings using application dialog, they are also written into the assembly.cs as you did manually.

I personally prefer to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

It is OK to do this, but the Properties UI does not support it.  (Even in higher versions)